# changing mongod dbpath raise permission error

Tags: mongodb

I needed more space on my mongo database so I went to my local computer shop, bought a new hard drive, installed it.  Then I copied all the files from `/var/lib/mongodb` to `/media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/` and changed the ownership of `/media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/` with the command `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/`.  Then, I changed the config file at `/etc/mongod.conf` to point to the good data directory.  Basically, I followed the instruction at [Changing MongoDB data store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory).

The permissions looks good, the config file looks fine too, but when I start mongodb using `sudo service mongod start` I have the following exception in my logs

```
014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5899 port=27017 
dbpath=/media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/ 64-bit host=miaou
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] git version: 255f67a66f9603c59380b2a389e386910bbb52cb
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build12.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/", terminating
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-07-16T09:11:37.362-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Any idea what goes wrong?  When I simply run `sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` everything works fine.  So I suppose it is a permission problem.

cheers!

Comment: Did you install mongod using an `rpm` or `deb` package?

Comment: I followed the instructions.  It uses deb.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: even a damned `chmod -R 777` did not help!

Comment: Did you `sudo chown mongod:mongod /media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/`?

Comment: the mongod user and group do not exist.  But the mongodb does but it changes nothing.  Do you know if I can see what happen under the hood of service mongod start (with debug or verbatim mode)?

Comment: There isn't much magic "under the hood" aside from `mongod` trying to open the files in the `dbpath` with r/w access. You definitely don't want to chmod 777; you should set the ownership to match the user your `mongod` service is running as. Given you need to provide more information to troubleshoot this problem, you might want to post on the [mongodb-user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) for more back & forth discussion. FYI, with the 2.6 Ubuntu installer, the expected ownership on your `dbpath` should be `mongodb:mongodb` (which it looks like you've already tried)

Comment: A gist/pastebin link with an `ls -laR /media/didier/mongodb/mongodb/` would help clarify the current permissions. It also seems odd to have `mongodb/mongodb` in the path; is that correct or should there just be a single `mongodb` directory?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the hard drive is not accessible to the *mongodb* user.  To share a hard drive between all users, you need to change the `/etc/fstab` by adding the following line:

```
UUID=a43bc179-f0e5-464b-bd77-1be6a7581ec2   /media/mongodb ext4  defaults  0   0
```

That will mount the hard drive to the `/media/mongodb` directory at boot time.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab for more information.

---

In short, to use a different hard drive as data location on mongodb on a ubuntu machine one needs to do the following three steps:

1. make sure the *mongodb* user can access the new hard drive (fstab)
2. make sure the user *mongodb* has access to the data directory (chown)
3. change the mongo config file (/etc/mongod.conf)

Comment: How does this share it among all users?  Is it the 'defaults' option?

Comment: To answer my own question, I don't think this does 'share it among all users' necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you need to change permissions of your /media mount point to have r+x (read and execute) for 'other' groups and users; at least that fixed it for me.  Doing

```
sudo chmod a+rx /media
```

will do it.  You want to make sure this is also true for the whole path to the mongodb data I think, so you could do `sudo chmod -R a+rx /media` to make it recursive, or change the permissions for the drive, then each subfolder up to the mongodb folder:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /media/didier
sudo chmod a+rx /media/didier/mongodb
sudo chmod a+rx /media/didier/mongodb/mongodb
```