# chown in a mounted NTFS partition in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to move my mongodb database files to another partition, which is mounted at boot at `/media/my_username/files`.

I'm trying to use the solution mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702994/4169641).

I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions), and successfully mounted the partition at boot time with:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/the_partiotion_uuid
```

However, the user that I used to run `mongod`, which is mongodb, have no access to the partition. When I run:

```
sudo -u mongodb -s cd /media/my_username/files
```

The result shows that user mongodb has no permission to access the directory. And through some searching and trying, it seems that `chown` is not functional in a mounted partition, the permission is set when the partition is mounted.

How do I solve this?

THX

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the partition as `mongodb` user in order to access the files.

Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191085/how-to-mount-a-drive-for-other-user-than-root). It shows how to mount a partition as a user other than root.

Comment: if I mount the partition as `mongodb`, can I access the partition as other users?

Comment: I haven't tried it. But i think you can only access as `mongodb` user.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way around. Instead of start mongod as a service at boot time, I wrote a script to run it manually:

```
sudo nohup mongod --dbpath /media/me/partition_name/mongodb &
```

Since I mount `/media/me/partition_name/` at boot, there's no problem.