# docker backup and restore mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

Create data only container:

```
docker create -v /mongodb_data --name mongodb_data mongo
```

Create monogdb container:

```
docker run --volumes-from mongodb_data --name mongo_db --restart always -d mongo
```

Then to use mongodb in my own container I use the link command:

```
--link mongo_db:mongo
```

So everything works fine. Now I want to backup the mongodb according to the docs: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes and this command:

```
docker run --volumes-from mongodb_data -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /mongodb_data
```

However the created tar file has just an empty `/mongodb_data` folder. The folder contains not a single file.

Any ideas whats wrong? I am using docker 1.7 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your data only container. You make your volume with path `/mongodb_data` which doesn't store any mongo db data. By default, the mongo db storage path is `/data/db` (according to [this](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) #Where to Store Data Section)

As the result, your mongodb data is not saved in your data only container. So here is a workaround:

- copy `/data/db` to `/mongodb_data` in your mongodb container `docker exec -it mongo_db bash` then `cp -r /data/db/* /mongodb_data/`
- make a backup by following the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#back-up-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) you mentioned
- build a new data only container and load the backup
- remove current `mongo_db` container and recreate a new one with the new data only container

OR, you can modify your `mongodb` config, to change the default directory to `/mongodb_data` once you copied all data from `/data/db` to `/mongodb_data`. You may find this useful [Changing MongoDB data store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bwnyasse/docker-mongodb-worker/) that provides docker container for many jobs ( import, export , dump )