# Cant set path for mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I already installed it, but when I run `mongod` I get:

`"NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\\data\\db\\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}`,

so searching I need to create a path to store the data, I want to save in the folder of my project, this is the route:

`C:\Users\User_name\mern-todo-app\backend\mongodb\data\db`,

so it will be:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "C:\Users\User_name\mern-todo-app\backend\mongodb\data\db"
```

but it says that can't find the route, I'm not good at using the console so, if anyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657010/how-to-set-default-dbpath-for-mongodb-in-windows-7

Comment: React JS is a frontend library, won't connect to Mongo DB.