# mongodb data finds commands on cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am learning node and mongodb

My app is working fine (Its is online tutorial app)

**I have two Question**

```
// define model =================
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text : String
});


// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});
```

I hope you understand my code (Its todo adding app)

1) Is 'Todo' is collection in mongoDB ? 
I typed on cmd `db.collection.find()`  but nothing result ? , Which command i use on cmd to see data here

2) Can I open DB data storage file in my editor with any tool ?

[Online tutorial app link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to select the database.

> use database-name

You can find the list of collections in database using the following command.

> show collections

You can find the list for databases using the following command

> show dbs

Then use the `db.collection.find()` command.

use `help` command to find list of commands.

Comment: Success , and 2) Can I open DB data storage file in my editor with any tool ?

Comment: I am not sure. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory

Comment: @Hunter I use the program MongoVUE to review and manage my MongoDB databases both locally and on production sites like OpenShift and Heroku.