# Changing mongo dbpath to external drive causes server failure

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use an external drive to store my mongo collections. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory) question, I changed `dbPath` in `/etc/mongod.conf`  from `/var/lib/mongodb` to `/media/user/drive/mongodb`. I also `chown`'d the new path to the `mongodb` user.

However, when I `sudo service start mongod`, I cannot start the server:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-12-07 22:27:09 CET; 2s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 63819 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
   Main PID: 63819 (code=exited, status=100)

Dec 07 22:27:09 user-ThinkPad-T480s systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 07 22:27:09 user-ThinkPad-T480s systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Dec 07 22:27:09 user-ThinkPad-T480s systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I change `dbPath` back to `/var/lib/mongodb` it starts again. How can I fix this such that I can use the path on my external drive?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OS you run and which version of MongoDB.
On Amazon Linux 2 it's mongod user not mongodb for MongoDB-5.0
Make sure you ran **chown** with **-R** flag

> -rw-r----- 1 mongod mongod 8.6M Dec 10 00:59 mongod.log

Also check logs for more hints, default location should be under

> /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. There's no mongod user on my machine, only mongodb.